# Spree: Listing variants on product index pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, spree

How can I list the variants of products on category pages that list products?

They don't need to be selectable; this is to show that there are options to be chosen and their respective prices.

I'm currently using Spree 0.70.1.

I'm new to Ruby and Ruby on Rails. I have successfully achieved some modifications such as locales and minor tweaks, but would appreciate clear instructions or pointers as I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by a kind soul in #spree IRC:

```
<% product.variants.each do |variant| %>
  <%= variant.options_text %>
  <%= number_to_currency variant.price %>
<% end %>
```